# NSDate vs. UIWebView's Javascript Date object

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, uiwebview, nsdate

I ran a test [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] vs. printing out UIWebView's Date().getTime(), they seem to be a few seconds off. Initially I thought it's because I'm printing both on the main thread, but that shouldn't cause a few seconds delay should it?
Here's my testing code if it helps.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0001 target:self selector:@selector(debugTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)debugTime
{
    NSLog(@"%1.6f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
}
```

And UIWebView loads a local HTML file with this code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    window.setInterval("time()",1/100000);
});
function time() {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(d.getTime()/1000);
}
```

I inspect the console via Safari's Web Inspector.

iOS prints: 1376552964.625462

Javascript prints: 1376552967.63

I need a way to synchronize time both via native Objective-C as well as in a UIWebView. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried converting your both time stamp strings to date.

iOS prints==>2013-08-15 07:49:24 +0000

Javascript prints==> 2013-08-15 07:49:27 +0000

using the code,

```
NSString * timeStampString = @"1376552967.63";
NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString doubleValue];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

I suspect its because the time webview takes to load the page and to excute the javascript date function.The reason why i am saying this because,the time difference between the two(iOS & javascript) is just 3 seconds..

For more information visit==>[What are common pitfalls of timestamp based syncing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186542/what-are-common-pitfalls-of-timestamp-based-syncing)